# Why is my output already sorted in python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}
stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple" : 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

for item in prices:
    print item
    print "price: %s" % prices[item]
    print "stock: %s" % stock[item]
```

The outout of the following code gives the following output

```
orange
price: 1.5
stock: 32
pear
price: 3
stock: 15
banana
price: 4
stock: 6
apple
price: 2
stock: 0
None
```

I want to ask why is it displayed in this way (in sorted order) . Isn't banana should come first , then apple , orange and pear ?

Comment: Search for the gazillion other duplicates about ordering in dictionaries...

Answer (score 1):

It's not sorted. You use a dictionary to store your data. Standard dictionaries in Python are unordered. They basically are a hashmap of keys connected to values. The order you see is the order of keys in the dict's hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

an unordered dictionary is most probably implemented as a  [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (in fact, the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) states this outright) where the order of elements is well-defined but not immediately obvious. Your observations match the rules of a hash table perfectly: apparent arbitrary, but constant order.

Thanks to @konrad-rudolph

Answer (score 1):

`dict` doesn't guarantee sorting, it is basically a [Hash Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Order is based on `hash()` function, you may check this in interpreter:

```
>>> hash('orange') < hash('pear')
True
```

To print keys in really sorted order, use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or apply `sorted()` while iterating keys:

```
for item in sorted(prices.keys()):
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Python `Dict` has no order.So you can use `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderedDict
for i, j in  OrderedDict(sorted(prices.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])).items():
    print i, j

orange 1.5
apple 2
pear 3
banana 4
```